# Positivity of the spectrum of a quasi-stationary signal

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, signal-processing, analytic-functions

I am working on the "System identification : theory for the user" by Lennart Ljung (freely available [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwisgfT59Ib-AhVPT6QEHUrxBdgQFnoECCMQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mit.bme.hu%2Fsystem%2Ffiles%2Foktatas%2Ftargyak%2F9132%2FLjung_L_System_Identification_Theory_for_User-ed2.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2HrPzAZbx3g2OgZZoFhU67)) and it is one of these books which contains exercises but no answers... My exercise is the 2G2 p47.

The context is as follows :

s is a discrete scalar real quasi-stationary signal, a quasi-stationary signal being a stochastic signals that verifies :
$$
\exists C>0\quad\text{such that :}
$$
$$\forall t\in \mathbb{N}\quad\vert E[s(t)]\vert \leq C  \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$
$$\forall t,r\in \mathbb{N}\quad\vert E[s(t)s(r)]\vert \leq C  \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$
$$\forall\tau\in\mathbb{Z}\quad R_s(\tau) = \lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{t=1}^{N}E[s(t)s(t-\tau)]\quad\text{exists}\tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

We assume the spectrum exists. In this context it is defined as :

$$\Phi_s(\omega) = \sum_{\tau=-\infty}^{+\infty}R_s(\tau)e^{-i\omega\tau}\tag{4}\label{eq4}$$

My question bears on question **(ii)** of the following exercise :
$$
\begin{split}
&\textbf{(i) : }\quad \forall\omega\in\mathbb{R}\quad\Phi_s(\omega) \quad\text{is real }\\
&\textbf{(ii) : }\quad \forall\omega\in\mathbb{R}\quad\Phi_s(\omega)\geq 0\\
&\textbf{(iii) : }\quad \forall\omega\in\mathbb{R}\quad\Phi_s(\omega)=\Phi_s(-\omega)\\
\end{split}
$$

Quickly, the answer for **(i)** and **(iii)** :

Remark how in \ref{eq3} the sum starts at $t=1$ so, by convention we can set $s(t)=0$ for $t\leq 0$. Then we may note that :
$$\forall N\geq 1\quad \sum_{t=1}^{N}s(t)s(t+\tau)=\sum_{k=\tau+1}^{N+\tau}s(k)s(k-\tau)$$
then via the definition \ref{eq3}, it comes easy that :

$$\forall\tau\in\mathbb{Z}\quad R_s(\tau)=R_s(-\tau)\tag{5}\label{eq5}$$

from that, by using this symmetry in the sum of \ref{eq4}, we get :

$$\Phi_s(\omega) =R_s(0) +2\sum_{\tau=1}^{+\infty}R_s(\tau)cos(\omega\tau)\tag{6}\label{eq6}$$

which instantly solves **(i)** and **(iii)**.

Now, how to solve **(ii)**? Here is what I tried :

I thought that probably $\Phi_s$ is continuous. Then if we can show that, except if $s=0$ $\Phi_s$ does not cancel then $\Phi_s$ is of constant sign. Just one evaluation (maybe $\Phi_s(0)\leq 0$?) and then we're good but I don't know how to proceed.

Another idea I had is that if I have
$$\sum_{\tau=-\infty}^{+\infty}\vert R_s(\tau)\vert < R_s(0)\tag{7}\label{eq7}$$
then I can conclude. But I cannot even show that the sum in \ref{eq7} exists. All I have is that I'm pretty sure that the relation \ref{eq3} defines a scalar product and therefore, by Cauchy Schwarz, we should get that :

$$\forall \tau\in\mathbb{Z}\quad R_s(\tau)\leq R_s(0)$$

Does anybody know how to solve this? I'm sure I missed something stupid.